# How to integrate $5^{5^{5^x}}5^{5^x}5^x$?

Tags: integration

How to integrate $5^{5^{5^x}}5^{5^x}5^x$ ?
I guess it's simple but can't figure it out !

Comment: Using the chain rule, try to calculate the derivative of $5^{5^{5^x}}$. The answer looks a lot like your formula.

Comment: Can we at least simplify the problem so that it's $e^{e^{e^x}}e^{e^x}e^x$?  I see no reason why the "five" is important here.

Answer (score 8):

Start with $5^x=y\implies5^x\cdot\ln5\ dx=dy$ to get

$$\ln5\int5^{5^{5^x}}5^{5^x}5^x=\int 5^{5^y}5^ydy$$

again set $5^y=u$

Comment: neat and simple! +1

Answer (score 5):

Let $u=5^{5^x}$, then $x = \frac{\frac{\ln(u)}{\ln(5)}}{\ln{5}}$ and $du = 5^{x+5^x}\ln^2(5)\hspace{.1cm} dx \implies dx = \frac{5^{-x-5^x}}{\ln^2(5)} \hspace{.1cm} du$. Thus we transform

$ \begin{align}
\int 5^{5^{5^x}} 5^{5^x} 5^x \hspace{.1cm} dx &= \int 5^uu5^x \frac{5^{-x-5^x}}{\ln^2(5)} \hspace{.1cm} du \\
&= \int \frac{u5^{u-5\frac{\frac{\ln(u)}{\ln(5)}}{\ln{5}}}}{\ln^2(5)} \hspace{.1cm} du \\
&= \frac{1}{\ln^2(5)} \int u5^{u-5\frac{\frac{\ln(u)}{\ln(5)}}{\ln{5}}} \hspace{.1cm} du \\
&= \frac{1}{\ln^2(5)} \int 5^u \hspace{.1cm} du \\
&= \frac{1}{\ln^2(5)} \frac{5^u}{\ln(5)} \\
&= \frac{1}{\ln^2(5)} \frac{5^{5^{5^x}}}{\ln(5)} \\
&= \frac{5^{5^{5^x}}}{\ln^3(5)}
\end{align}$

Comment: Apologies to be redundant to lab bhattacharjee's superior and infinitely more simple answer, but I suppose if one wants for unnecessary detail. . . .